# How to get rid of hard water stains on the roof from an evaporative cooler

Tags: evaporative-cooling

My swamp cooler was leaking over the summer, left some nice ugly stains on the roof heading down to the edge.

Can I get rid of them somehow?  I tried scrubbing with vinegar but it didn't seem to do "enough"...

[image]

Comment: There are store bought products for hard water stains.  Do not think scrubbing and shingles should go together.

Comment: Heck, just get some paint or stain.

Comment: CLR, limeaway, or the like should help a lot. or just more vinegar for longer or stronger, like 30%.

Comment: @Huesmann Make that an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for the suggestion, I gave CLR a shot and it worked "better" than vinegar, it fixed about 30% of the white aspect.  Guess it soaks in? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint or stain will cover that for a while, and you may not care after it wears off, because your swamp cooler may have fallen apart before then. ;)

Comment: Yep used spray paint once :) I think some manufacturers makes a "tintable" roof paint as well...thanks!